# Prevent formatting when submitting JSON string to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to POST JSON to a Node app, which will simply return it via a GET.
Client side, I generate a JSON string of the model, and POST it to the server:

```
$.post(serverURL, ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel), function(data) {}, "json");
```

This yields a string that looks like:

```
{"switches":[{"id":1,"name":"Living Room","state":false},{"id":2,"name":"Dining Room","state":false},{"id":3,"name":"Kitchen Room","state":true},{"id":4,"name":"Aviary","state":true}]}
```

Note that the "state" values are unquoted true/false, which is [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/). On the server, if I log the request body, I get the following:

```
{ switches:
[ { id: '1', name: 'Living Room', state: 'false' },
 { id: '2', name: 'Dining Room', state: 'false' },
 { id: '3', name: 'Kitchen Room', state: 'true' },
 { id: '4', name: 'Aviary', state: 'true' } ] }
```

Note the differences:

- It has quoted the true/false values
- It has unquoted object names
- The quotes are single quotes

My goal is to simply store the original JSON object in it's original string format, for a GET request later. What is doing this formatting, and how can I prevent it?

**Additional info per request**

My Node.JS code is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var model;

app.configure( function () {});

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    console.log(model);
res.send(model);
});

app.post('/', function (req,res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');   

    model = req.body;
    console.log(model);

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: How are you receiving and decoding the JSON on the server-side?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  - See my additional code sample above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

Your `post` call is not telling the server what kind of data you're sending. In particular, the last argument to [`post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (`dataType`, for which you're supplying `'post'`) is **not** the format of the data you're sending ***to*** the server, it's the format of the data you're expecting back ***from*** the server.

Separately, you're using KnockoutJS's `toJS` function. According to [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), this doesn't produce JSON, it produces a JavaScript object graph. To get a JSON string, you need to use `ko.toJSON`.

So my guess (and it is that) is that Express doesn't have enough information to work with and is applying the wrong decoding mechanism, and the data being sent is getting a bit mangled by jQuery trying to turn it into form data.

Try using the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function and specifying `contentType: "application/json"` and using `ko.toJSON`, e.g. something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type:       'POST',
  url:         serverURL,
  data:        ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel)),
  success:     function(data) {},
  dataType:    'json' // IF you're expecting JSON back
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

(Or possibly just `data: ko.toJSON(viewModel)`, I'm not deep enough into Knockout to know for sure.)

Comment: Thanks, agreed, it was my bonehead mistake of calling .toJS, rather than .toJSON. The data parameter should actually be ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel). The changes to the request don't appear to have been necessary to correct this problem, but I appreciate the additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I think, and got around it by calling JSON.stringify on the request body.  If anybody has a more proper solution I'd like to hear it, because this seems a bit weird.  But OTOH it works 8P.

My controller produced these logs:

```
------ req.body here ----------
[ { name: 'My Watchlist',
    stocks: [ 'AACC', 'AAPL', 'VZ', 'JPM' ] } ]
------ stringified req.body here ----------
[{"name":"My Watchlist","stocks":["AACC","AAPL","VZ","JPM"]}]
---- end ------
```

With this code at the start of the controller

```
console.log('------ req.body here ----------');
console.dir(req.body);
console.log('------ stringified req.body here ----------');
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
console.log('---- end ------');

try{
    var o = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
}
catch(e){...
```